# Screen as a service on systemd wont start

Tags: linux, systemd, gnu-screen, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to run screen on a systemd service as startup, so i can check on it later if needed, on an interactive shell, but the session wont stay up, and apparently it doesn't even start.

This is my unit file.

```
Description=MyService
After=network.target

[Service]
type=forking
User=<myuser>
Group=<myuser>
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -L -d -m -S myservice /home/myuser/runmycommands.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is my script

```
cd mysoftware
echo "This doesn't work" >> /home/myuser/log.log
./mysoftware
```

All I get is a dead screen:

```
        737.myservice   (02/23/2021 10:59:18 PM)        (Dead ???)
```

If i copy the ExecStart line and run it directly, it works.

```
myuser@mymachine:~$ /usr/bin/screen -L -d -m -S myservice /home/myuser/runmycommands.sh
myuser@mymachine:~$ screen -wipe
There is a screen on:
        1026.myservice  (02/23/2021 11:14:46 PM)        (Detached)
```

Any ideas?